# Why jQuery Ajax send Get request before of Post?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, devexpress

I want to pass my combobox value on button click event in ASP.Net Mvc but it send get request first then send post request. But I don't want to send Get request.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("#btnSave").click(function () {
            $.ajax({
                url: '@Url.Action("ExportButton")',
                type: 'POST',
                data: {
                    Parameter: mycombobox.GetValue()
                }
            });
            $('#btnSave').unbind('click');
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
```

Any idea?

Edit:

Here is my button:

```
@Html.DevExpress().Button(itemSettings =>
{
    itemSettings.Width = 150;
    itemSettings.Styles.Native = true;

    itemSettings.Name = "btnSave";
    itemSettings.Text = "Save";
    itemSettings.UseSubmitBehavior = false ;
    itemSettings.RouteValues = new { Controller = "Report", Action = "ExportButton"};
}
).GetHtml()
```

Combobox:

```
@Html.DevExpress().ComboBox( itemSettings =>
{

    var properties = itemSettings.Properties;
    properties.Caption = "Save As ";
    properties.Items.Add("PDF", "PDF");
    properties.Items.Add("EXCEL", "EXCEL");
    properties.Items.Add("CSV", "CSV");
    itemSettings.Name = "mycombobox";

    properties.ValueType = typeof(string);
}
).GetHtml()
```

Edit 2:

I realised that my jquery send "get" method before "Post" method.

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: immediate solution is to have ajax in a `if(mycombobox.GetValue()){}`

Comment: are you somehow preventing the default action of the button? It may be submitting the form too?

Comment: Show the markup/html code

Comment: post your html code

Comment: What about event.stopPropagation?

Comment: I am working on Devexpress and I posted my Button and Combobox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think your Ajax is running twice. Based on the image you've included, these requests are coming from different sources. The first one is a GET from the document and the second is the Ajax call by POST where you can see it is using XHR. Try to hover over or click on each line in order to get more detailed information.

Comment: Like you said, problem is the other line in button create part.

Answer (score 0):

did you had tried this way?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("#btnSave").unbind().click(function () {//unbind your click event here
            $.ajax({
                url: '@Url.Action("ExportButton")',
                type: 'POST',
                data: {
                    Parameter: mycombobox.GetValue()
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for answer but it didn't worked. Same result.

Answer (score 0):

[The docs](http://api.jquery.com/click/) state that click is a shortcut method for `.on("click", handler)` and suggests using `.off("click")` for unbinding, instead of `unbind()`. Give it a try !

Answer (score 0):

I finally solved the problem.

```
@Html.DevExpress().Button(itemSettings =>
{
    itemSettings.Width = 150;
    itemSettings.Styles.Native = true;

    itemSettings.Name = "btnSave";
    itemSettings.Text = "Save";
    itemSettings.UseSubmitBehavior = false ;
    itemSettings.RouteValues = new { Controller = "Report", Action = "ExportButton"}; // This line send Get request!
}
).GetHtml()
```

When I deleted **itemSettings.RouteValues** line, problem solved.